# Fire a fuction after Google Maps AutoComplement

Tags: javascript, google-maps, autocomplete

Im trying to run a Function after the user select a address on the **Google Address List**. I tried with `onBlur` but the action would fire before the user could select the address giving me an incomplete one.

I read these topics:

[How to fire place_changed event for Google places auto-complete on Enter key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12816428/how-to-fire-place-changed-event-for-google-places-auto-complete-on-enter-key)

[Google Places API - place_changed listener not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11271300/google-places-api-place-changed-listener-not-working)

[Events other than 'place_changed' for Google Maps Autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32193020/events-other-than-place-changed-for-google-maps-autocomplete)

And I tried with `place_changed` but still I cant get to run my function.

**HTML**

```
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">    
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=EDITED(MY KEY)&libraries=places"></script><script src="mapa.js" language="Javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>


          <input type="text" name="street" id="0" onFocus="autoComplete(this);">


</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function autoComplete(adress)
{

    var input = document.getElementById(adress.id);
    var options = { componentRestrictions: {
      country: 'fr'

    }};

    new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);

    google.maps.event.addListener(gmaps, 'place_changed', function () {
       getPlace(adress); 
    });

}

function getPlace(adress)
{
   alert(adress.value);   
}
```

What I am missing?

For an alternative solution is there anyway to make the `onBlur` or `onChange` only fire after the user select something on the auto complete list? This would be a better solution to my problem I think.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How are you including the API? Are you including the places library?  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: Sorry geocode. I edited to put the entire code into my question. I edited my Google Key for security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i saw what i was missing.

On the `new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);` i had to save it on a variable like `gmaps = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);` and then call it on the Listener:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(gmaps, 'place_changed', function () {
   getPlace(adress); 
});
```

Rookie mistake.